# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am trying to work with SignalR and JavaScript and I came across the error "Uncaught TypeError: Undefined", which I don't understand.  Below is the code which is causing the problem.

HTML

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.chat;
        chat.Messenger = function (message) {
            $("#message").append("<li>" + message + "</li>");

        };

        $("#sendMessage").click(function () {
            var text = $("#txtMessage").val();
            chat.Send(text);
        });
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
<div>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Send Message</legend>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtMessage"  name="txtMessage"   />
        <input type="button" id="sendMessage" value="Send" />
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Message</legend>
        <ul id="message">

        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Code

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is causing that error?

Comment: this happen when you don't defined function ..on which line you get this error

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery instead of $, so your script will be like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        var chat = jQuery.connection.chat;
        chat.Messenger = function (message) {
            jQuery("#message").append("<li>" + message + "</li>");

        };

        jQuery("#sendMessage").click(function () {
            var text = jQuery("#txtMessage").val();
            chat.Send(text);
        });
        jQuery.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

Hope, It helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure, $ is defined at the time it's called. Putting this snippet

```
if( typeof $ == "undefined" ){ $ = jQuery; }
```

before Your JS will do the work or You.